# Deklination von Adjektiv, die auf einen Vokal enden

Tags: adjective, declension, adjective-ending

Ich kenne die Regeln, die besagen wie ein Adjektiv in den Kasus Nominativ, Akkusativ, Dativ und Genitiv konjugiert wird (nach bestimmten und unbestimmten Artikeln sowie ohne Artikel).
Z. B. mit Artikel (Singular):

> Nom: der große Betrieb
>
> Akk: den großen Betrieb
>
> Dat: dem großen Betrieb
>
> Gen: des großen Betriebs

Aber wie ist es mit den Adjektiven, die auf einen Vokal enden? Beispielsweise *prima*. Heißt es z. B. "die primae Wohnung"?
Und wie sieht es mit der Leichtigkeit bei der Aussprache aus?

Weitere Adjektive:

> gaga, leise, lila, klasse, rosa, ...

Comment: @Tofro Magst du für die Nachwelt, wenn du schon editierst, noch ganze, lesbare Sätze daraus machen? ;)

Comment: Deine Frage bezieht sich auf die Deklination der Adjektive. Ich habe entsprechend den Titel der Frage angepasst, so dass dieser aussagekräftiger ist. Den Body der Frage musste ich leider auch sehr stark abändern, inhaltlich ist dieser aber unverändert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es gibt im Deutschen Adjektive, die *gar nicht* flektiert werden können. Einige deiner Beispiele gehören dazu:

> N: Der prima Schuh
> A: den prima Schuh
> G: des prima Schuhs
> D: dem prima Schuh

Dabei handelt es sich zum großen Teil um Adjektive, die ursprünglich aus Substantiven entstanden sind (z.B. *prima*, *super*, *klasse*) und z.B. manche Farben (*lila*, *rosa*).

Andere Beispiele für nicht deklinierbare Adjektive sind z.B. adjektivisch verwendete Ortsnamen, wie z.B. im *Bonner Hauptbahnhof* oder *Kölner Dom*.

Eine weitere Klasse von Adjektiven, die nicht dekliniert werden, findet sich in stehenden Ausdrücken, wie

> eitel Sonnenschein
>
> Jung Siegfried

*leise* in deinen Beispielen lässt sich dagegen prima (sic) flektieren:

> N: die leise Musik
> A: die leise Musik
> G: der leisen Musik
> D: der leisen Musik

Comment: Vielen dank @tofro und für die Korrektion des schnellen Tippens

Answer (score 0):

Prima, einige Farbadjektive und etliche andere sind indeklinabel.

[prima im Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/prima)

Comment: Viele Farbadjektive (gelb, rot, blau,....) sind sehr wohl deklinabel

Comment: Danke @tofro, bin übers Ziel hinausgeschossen und werde meine Antwort modifizieren.